# Solution of a differential equation involving $3$ variables $x,y,t$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> **QUESTION**: Solve the differential equation- $$\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dt}+2x+y=0$$ $$\frac{dy}{dt}+5x+3y=0$$

I am unable to progress in solving these equations. For by any manipulation, I am unable to reduce the $2$ equations to form an equation containing only $2$ variables. Also, I have this doubt that the information is insufficient.

Am I correct? Please help.

Comment: Only $t$ is a variable here. $y,x$ are functions $x(t),y(t)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplistic approach $$\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dt}+2x+y=0\tag 1$$ $$\frac{dy}{dt}+5x+3y=0\tag 2$$ From $(2)$ $$x=-\frac 15\left(3y+\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\tag 3$$ $$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac 15\left(3\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\right)\tag 4$$ Use $(3)$ and $(4)$ in $(1)$ and get $$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+y=0\tag 5$$ Solve it for $y$ and use the result in $(3)$ to get $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting the second equation from the first gives the first-order system (written in matrix form) $$\begin{pmatrix}\dot{x}\\\dot y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ -5 & -3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}$$
or simply $\dot{v}=A v$. This is similar to the ODE for $e^t$, suggesting a solution of the form $v=e^{\lambda t}v_0$ which in turn implies the eigenvalue problem $Av=\lambda v$. Since $A$ is a 2-by-2 matrix, we conclude that the general solution is of the form $v=v_1 e^{\lambda_1 t}+v_2 e^{\lambda_2 t}$ where $v_1,v_2$ are eigenvectors with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$.

Comment: @A.E.Janett Nice catch on the typo, I was careless.

Comment: The eigenvalues are $\pm i$, so one can look for solutions of the form $a \, \cos (t - \alpha)$.

Comment: @Semiclassical thanks! Great description of the solution method.

Answer (score 2):

Use Laplace transform:

- $$x'(t)+y'(t)+2x(t)+y(t)=0\Longleftrightarrow sx(s)-x(0)+sy(s)-y(0)+2x(s)+y(s)=0$$
- $$y'(t)+5x(t)+3y(t)=0\Longleftrightarrow sy(s)-y(0)+5x(s)+3y(s)=0$$

Now, find $x(s)$ and $y(s)$:

- $$x(s)=\frac{x(0)+y(0)-sy(s)-y(s)}{2+s}$$
- $$y(s)=\frac{y(0)-5x(s)}{3+s}$$

Now, substitute them into each other to find:

- $$x(s)=\frac{x(0)(3+s)+2y(0)}{1+s^2}$$
- $$y(s)=\frac{y(0)(s-3)-5x(0)}{1+s^2}$$

Now, when you use inverse Laplace transform you'll find that:

- $$x(t)=x(0)\cos(t)+(3x(0)+2y(0))\sin(t)$$
- $$y(t)=y(0)\cos(t)-(3y(0)+5x(0))\sin(t)$$

Comment: Nice solution. One possible confusion: You denote the Laplace transform as $x(s)$, but when you use $x(0)$ it's intended as $x(t)$ at $t=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ and $y$ be functions of $t$. We have
$$x'+y'+2x+y=0$$
$$y'+5x+3y=0$$
so
$$x'-3x-2y=0$$
$$y'+5x+3y=0$$

Let $$r(t)=\begin{bmatrix} x(t)\\y(t) \end{bmatrix}.$$

$$r'(t)=\begin{bmatrix} 3 && 2 \\ -5 && -3 \\ \end{bmatrix}r(t)$$

Suppose $r(t)=ce^{\lambda t}$ for some nonzero constant vector $c$.

The differential equation becomes $$\lambda c e^{\lambda t}=\begin{bmatrix} 3 && 2 \\ -5 && -3 \\ \end{bmatrix}ce^{\lambda t}$$ so
$$\lambda c=\begin{bmatrix} 3 && 2 \\ -5 && -3 \\ \end{bmatrix}c$$.

We need to find the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of the matrix:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 && 2 \\ -5 && -3 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

The characteristic polynomial is:

$$\det(A-\lambda I)=\lambda^2+1.$$

So setting this equal to $0$, the roots are $\lambda= i,-i$.

The corresponding eigenvector for the eigenvalue $i$ of $A$, is $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \frac{i-3}{2} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

The corresponding eigenvector for the eigenvalue $-i$ of $A$, is $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \frac{-i-3}{2} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

So: $$r(t)=\begin{bmatrix} c_1e^{it}+c_2e^{-it} \\ c_1\frac{i-3}{2}e^{it} -c_2\frac{i+3}{2}e^{-it} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ where $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{C}$